# Pass vb6 form to .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, interop

I am using interop to use .Net controls in vb6 application and would like to know if it is possible to pass vb6 form reference as an argument of a method.

I have .net control's init method signature defined as the following:

```
public bool Init(int Arg1, int Arg2, bool Arg3, int Arg4, int Arg5)
```

And I would like to pass ref of the vb6 form which calls this method as another argument.

Comment: [Calling C# Method from VB6](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10016805/calling-c-assembly-from-vb6.aspx) I would suggest reading this as well as doing a `google` search I saw tons of articles when I just did a google search

Comment: Thanks for the comment,  I have got the basic interop going already. And I did search google as well as stackoverflow specifically and I couldn't find anything that I wanted yet. The link you have posted seems to only contain the basic interop.

Comment: What do you want to do with the form in the c# code? Would passing the window handle suffice?